# Unexpected end of JSON input error with what seems to be a a valid JSON

Tags: javascript, json, database

```
var jsonPayload = '{"search" : "' + srch + '", "userID" : "' + userID + '"}';

var url = urlBase + '/SearchContacts.' + extension;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
try
{

    //document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML = "Contact(s) has been retrieved";

    // Send the Payload
    xhr.send(jsonPayload);

    //document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML = jsonPayload;
    //document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;

    var jsonObject = JSON.parse( xhr.responseText );

    document.getElementById("userName").innerHTML = jsonObject;
```

This is the code I have in my javascript file ^

This is the JSON being sent to the server

```
{
  "search": "re",
  "userID": "27"
}
```

And this is what it responds with

```
    "results":[
    {
        "0" : {
                "ID":"12",
                "firstName":"Reia",
                "lastName":"Drucker",
                "email":"newContactsEmail",
                "phone":"newContactsPhone",
                "date created":"2020-05-24 12:49:48",
                "address":"newContactsAddress",
                "city":"newContactsCity",
                "state":"newContactsState",
                "zip code":"newContactsZIPCode",
                "pronouns":"newContactsPronouns",
                "userID":"27"
            },
        "1" : {
                "ID":"27",
                "firstName":"regular",
                "lastName":"person",
                "email":"qw",
                "phone":"ew",
                "date created":"2020-05-25 15:04:55",
                "address":"r",
                "city":"s",
                "state":"t",
                "zip code":"u",
                "pronouns":"v",
                "userID":"27"
            },
        "2" : {
                "ID":"28",
                "firstName":"regular2",
                "lastName":"girl",
                "email":"q",
                "phone":"w",
                "date created":"2020-05-25 15:06:37",
                "address":"e",
                "city":"r",
                "state":"t",
                "zip code":"yy",
                "pronouns":"b",
                "userID":"27"
            }
        }
    ],
    "error":""
}
```

I have no idea as to why it's getting the error since both JSONs are valid. Any help in regards to what I would have to change in order to avoid this error would be greatly appreciated as I honestly have no idea myself at this point.

[Validation from external site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra5WG.png)

Comment: Please share the exact string value of `xhr.responseText`.

Comment: The way you are constructing your `jsonPayload` is also pretty sketchy and likely to cause (additional) problems as well with unconstrained values. You should always construct your JSON strings with `JSON.stringify`, e.g. `const jsonPayload = JSON.stringify({search: srch, userID});`. If you are not doing this on the server as well, that is likely the source of your problem.